# How can I separate a number/alpha text string into two XML elements in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt

Is it possible to separate a number/alpha text string into two XML elements in XSLT 1.0?

My input XML is:

```
<root>
<tocsectionnumber>1Funding and investing</tocsectionnumber>
<tocsectionnumber>2Rules and articles</tocsectionnumber>
<tocsectionnumber>3Summary and conclusion</tocsectionnumber>
</root>
```

I would like my output to be:

```
<TocItem>
<TocItemNumber>1</TocItemNumber>
<TocItemTitle>Funding and investing</TocItemTitle>
</TocItem>
<TocItem>
<TocItemNumber>2</TocItemNumber>
<TocItemTitle>Rules and articles</TocItemTitle>
</TocItem>
<TocItem>
<TocItemNumber>3</TocItemNumber>
<TocItemTitle>Summary and conclusion</TocItemTitle>
</TocItem>
```

My number string could be any 1-3 digit number and the alpha string is a heading/title.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to use a recursive template to count the leading digits, e.g.

```
<xsl:template name="leadingDigits">
  <xsl:param name="text" select="." />
  <xsl:param name="count" select="0" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <!-- check if the first character is a digit - when converted to number, any
         digit will equal itself, any non-digit will be NaN which does _not_
         equal itself -->
    <xsl:when test="number(substring($text, 1, 1)) =
                    number(substring($text, 1, 1))">
      <xsl:call-template name="leadingDigits">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring($text, 2)" />
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count + 1" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$count" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Now you can use that to separate the string into two parts

```
<xsl:template match="tocsectionnumber">
  <xsl:variable name="numDigits">
    <xsl:call-template name="leadingDigits" />
  </xsl:variable>

  <TocItem>
    <TocItemNumber>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, $numDigits)" />
    </TocItemNumber>
    <TocItemTitle>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(., $numDigits + 1)" />
    </TocItemTitle>
  </TocItem>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Ian, thats great, could I use a variation of this XSLT for another set of strings:

Comment: <tocscheduleheading>Schedule 1—Cats</tocscheduleheading>
<tocscheduleheading>Schedule 2—Dogs</tocscheduleheading>

Comment: @DR-WXP0062 if there's a specific separator character or string then it's trivial using `substring-before` and `substring-after`, otherwise you could use my method above but start looking for digits at the index 10 (the length of "Schedule " including the trailing space).

Comment: @DR-WXP0062 for the record, problems like this involving string manipulation are far easier if you are able to upgrade to a processor that understands XSLT 2.0, as you then have access to regular expression based operations.

Comment: Hi Ian, what about if my string is contained in parens e.g. <subsection>(1)This is level 2 para.</subsection> or <paragraph>(a)this is a level 3 para;</paragraph> ? Could I use substring-before and substring-after ? Thanks.

Comment: @DR-WXP0062 yes, in that particular case you've essentially got the `)` character denoting the boundary between the number and the text.

Comment: Hi Ian, HELP - I can't work out how to code the string manipulation for <subsection>(1)This is level 2 para.</subsection> or <paragraph>(a)this is a level 3 para;</paragraph>.

Comment: @DR-WXP0062 in that case the number is `substring(substring-before(., ')'), 2)` - from the second character up to but not including the first closing parenthesis - and the text is just `substring-after(., ')')` - everything after that parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

[groan] Who makes up these problems?

Anyway, try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="root/tocsectionnumber">
            <xsl:variable name="firstChar" select="substring(translate(., '0123456789', ''), 1, 1)" />
            <TocItem>
                <TocItemNumber><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., $firstChar)"/></TocItemNumber>
                <TocItemTitle><xsl:value-of select="concat($firstChar, substring-after(., $firstChar))"/></TocItemTitle>
            </TocItem>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this (or any other method) is going to bomb royally if the section title legitimately begins with a digit, e.g. "4. 101 Ways to Amuse Your Friends and Family".

Comment: Hi, I couldn't get this XSLT to work, but thanks for your time.